# Dropdownlist selectedindex doesn't work on page refresh

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, pageload

I'm having a problem with a very normal ASP.NET dropdownlist.
I have a dropdownlist in the page with `AutoPostback=false`.
And a code to generate dropdownlist’s content:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.dropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem("text1", "value1"));
        this.dropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem("text2", "value2"));
        this.dropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

- Run the page, and choose the second option: text2.
- After that, press F5, this will do a page load (note that I haven't done any postback yet, just change the selected item of Dropdownlist and press F5)

I expected that the dropdownlist will now selected the default item with `index = 0`, but the selected item is still the item “text2”- the item that I have chosen.  In this situation, the `this.dropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;` doesn’t work.

I totally don’t understand. Could anyone help me?

**Update:**  This behavior only happens in Firefox, it doesn't happen in Chrome/IE.

Comment: when you do a autopostback true the page if(!ispostaback) block does not hit and you get the txt2 as selected move >this.dropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;
out of the !ispostback block

Comment: but i'm doing AutoPostBack=false and the code this.dropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0; is being hit

Comment: My bad i couldn't read that in question

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're misunderstanding what *post back* means; it does *not* mean just a page refresh.  When you hit F5 in the browser, the original request will be sent to the server, and `Page.IsPostBack` will be *false*.

If you want to do an actual postback, add an `asp:Button` server control to the page and click it (or just set `AutoPostBack=true` on the DropDownList).

---

It seems like Firefox is doing some kind of client-side caching, so it doesn't make another round-trip to the server when you hit F5.  You can work around this by resetting the `select` element when the page loads.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('<%= dropDownList.ClientID %>').selectedIndex = 0;
</script>
```

(Note: put this at the bottom of the page so that it executes after the document has loaded.)

Comment: Thank you for your explain. What I'm trying to do here is to handle the case the the user will hit the F5 button (or press the refresh button in the browser).

Comment: @user1514431 I updated my answer to better address your question.

Comment: Great! I'm doing this to work around with FF too. But I'm also finding better solution because this behavior happens not only for dropdownlist but for every control in page (textbox, checkbox...). At least we got a solution as the last resort here.

Answer (score 1):

When you press F5, it will send the post headers along with the request.
Your last request was to select the second option. So that gets selected.

If you type the url again, or hit enter in the address bar; you will not send the post data.
In this case your SelectedIndex will be 0.

Comment: That is really interesting. So, is there a solution to forget the last request, and just select the first item as I want?

Comment: F5 is meant to resend the last request. You could look in the html5 history api. It may help. Also you can listen for F5 in javascript and set `location.href`.

Comment: I got your idea, seem using JavaScript to catch the f5 and redirect to the same page is the easiest way. I hope JavaScript also know when the user press the refresh button in the browser.

Comment: it turns out that your answer is not correct because I haven’t done any postback yet, so my last request is the first load.